# VS-generated clients of my service throw Deserialization exceptions

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, deserialization

Our WCF service has just one method:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "Service", Namespace = "http://myservice/")]
[ServiceKnownType("GetServiceKnownTypes", typeof(Service))]
public interface IService {
     Response Execute(Request request);
}

public class Service : IService {
     public static IEnumerable<Type> GetServiceKnownTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider) {
        return KnownTypesResolver.GetKnownTypes();
     }

     public Response Execute(Request request) { 
         return new MyResponse { Result = MyEnumHere.FirstValue }; 
     }
}
```

Both the `Request` and `Response` class includes a `ParameterCollection` member.

```
[Serializable]
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "ParameterCollection", Namespace = "http://myservice/")]
[KnownType("GetKnownTypes")]
public class ParameterCollection : Dictionary<string, object> {
        private static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes()
        {
            return KnownTypesResolver.GetKnownTypes();
        }
}
```

Subclasses of `Request` and `Response` store their values into the ParameterCollection value bag.

I am using the KnownTypesResolver class to provide type information across all Service objects.

```
public static class KnownTypesResolver {
     public static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes()
     {
         var asm = typeof(IService).Assembly;
         return asm
             .GetAllDerivedTypesOf<Response>() // an extension method
             .Concat(new Type[] {
                 typeof(MyEnumHere),
                 typeof(MyEnumHere?),
                 typeof(MyClassHere),
                 typeof(MyClassListHere),
             });
     }
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, everything should have proper type information for proxy class generation tools to produce well-defined classes client-side.
However, whenever one of the `Response` subclasses (i.e. `MyResponse`) contains an enum value such as `MyEnumHere`, WCF starts complaining that the deserializer has no knowledge of the MyEnumHere value. It should have. I provided a `KnownTypeAttribute` for this very reason.

The client-side proxy class does have a `MyEnumHere` enum in the Reference.cs file; the problem is that the `ParameterCollection` class has no `KnownTypeAttribute`s generated for it.

I resorted to hand-editing and including the following lines in the generated Reference.cs file:

```
//>
[KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(MyEnumHere))]
[KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(MyEnumHere?))]
[KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(MyClassHere))]
[KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(MyClassListHere))]
//<
public class ParameterCollection : Dictionary<string, object> { /* ... */ }
```

Hand-editing generated files is horrible. But this makes the clients work. What am I doing wrong? How can I define my Service objects so that the VS-proxy classes that are generated are correct from the get-go?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF does not work well with `Dictionary` because it is not  interoperable. You may use `Array`, `List` or custom collection to make sure that your data is properly serialized.

Code below  uses `List<ParamCollectionElement>` instead of `Dictionary`. I also removed some redundant attributes.

```
[DataContract]
public class Request
{
    [DataMember]
    public ParameterCollection ParameterCollection { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Response
{
    [DataMember]
    public ParameterCollection ParameterCollection { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyResponse : Response
{
    [DataMember]
    public MyEnumHere Result { get; set; }
}

public class ParamCollectionElement
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; } 
}


[CollectionDataContract(Name = "ParameterCollection")]
public class ParameterCollection : List<ParamCollectionElement> 
{

}

public static class KnownTypesResolver
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes()
    {
        return
            new Type[] {
                typeof(MyEnumHere),
                typeof(MyEnumHere?),
                typeof(Request),
                typeof(Response),
                typeof(MyResponse)
            };
    }
}

[DataContract]
public enum MyEnumHere
{
    [EnumMember]
    FirstValue,
    [EnumMember]
    SecondValue
}

[ServiceKnownType("GetServiceKnownTypes", typeof(Service))]
[ServiceContract(Name = "Service")]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Response Execute(Request request);
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetServiceKnownTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
    {
        return KnownTypesResolver.GetKnownTypes();
    }

    public Response Execute(Request request)
    {
        var result = new MyResponse
        {
            Result = MyEnumHere.FirstValue,
            ParameterCollection = new ParameterCollection()
        };

        result.ParameterCollection.Add(new ParamCollectionElement {Key = "one", Value = MyEnumHere.FirstValue});
        result.ParameterCollection.Add(new ParamCollectionElement { Key = "two", Value = new Response() });
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dharnitski. Your changes do fix the generated file, and this is a huge step forward. However, clients now lose the ability to index into the ParameterCollection like a regular Dictionary, which is something I'd rather have (hard to justify iterating over a collection to see if a key-value pair is there). Accepting this as the answer. Any additional feedback is welcome.

Comment: @Raine You can create and load Dictionary in client using data from custom collection.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `[DataContract]` on your enum and `[EnumMember]` on each of the enum members:

```
[DataContract]
public enum MyEnumHere
{
    [EnumMember]
    SomeValue,
    [EnumMember]
    OtherValue,
    [EnumMember]
    OneMoreValue
}
```

That should cause the proxy-enum to be built out (with its member values) in your client without having to manually change the Reference.cs file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I mentioned in the original post, the proxy file does have a MyEnumHere enum generated exactly like the server-side definition. The issue is that the deserializer has no knowledge of this type because of a missing KnownType attribute in the Reference.cs file, and my goal is have them generated automatically.

Comment: My bad, I read the exception wrongly (about the enum). I'm assuming the root cause here is being able to serialize the object value of the Dictionary.  Could you define that as a serializable type thereby precluding the need for the KnownTypeAttributes?  Just a thought.

Comment: sounds like a variant-like class (I'd store different types in different fields). I imagine it could help, but I believe it'd be easier for me (and for service consumers) to change the ParameterCollection class from a dict to a list rather than changing every entry value into a variant. That being said, thanks for your input, I like the different approach.